# C# Remove attachments from MimeContent

Tags: c#, mime, ews-managed-api

I want to remove the attachments of an email message MimeContent which has been read from an Exchange server.

Is there a library I can use for that or do I have to manually remove it from the mime content? 
Is there probably a solution where I can get the MimeContent of the email message without reading the attachments?

**Edit**: 
Usecase:
I need to return the mime content as a string via webservice twice. And in one case I need to return the mime content without attachments, because the attachments will be delivered in another way. And that for I have to cut the attachments from the mime content.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You want to delete the attachments?  Like this? : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633682%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I tried that but deleting the attachments from an object doesn't affect the mime content so I need to refresh it somehow but without another EWS call. Is there a way to do so? (I also added the use case above.)